# What's that fan sink? Fan sink family dimensions

Tags: cooling

I have a  graphics card with a Dynatron V35G fan sink on it. It looks like this:
[image: Dynatron V35G]
Now, this fan fits the card I'm using, but it is very noisy. I want to take the opportunity to try to improve my card and explore what other options I have in terms of cooling.

To aid my search I'm wondering how you would classify this fan family, and how you would search for a replacement fan of another brand?

50mm fan -- which seems to be the dimensions -- quite unsurprisingly returns loads of results with other ways of fastening the fan. I need something that fits this particular hole orientation, which I assume is a standard in some way.

Comment: CPU fans are defined by the CPU socket they are compatible with. So search for a fan based of the CPU socket you are using. Also, I'd say this is a computer question, not electronics question, so probably not on topic for this site.

Comment: Its a graphics card cooling fan.

Comment: Fans are usually specific to the make and model of graphics card, so search for "replacement fan <your model of card>".

Comment: you just need to keep it windy, it doesn't have to be pretty. my cpu fan is held on by zip ties.